# jQuery Parallax.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax.js

im trying to work with parallax.js but its not working regularly. My parallax div is not moving when im scrolling. I cant find the where the problem is. Here's the link im trying to work with. [parallax.html](http://grafiket.net/demo/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a lengthy comment with some suggestions to try.

Yeah, your parallax is not parallaxing... However, here are some things to try:

(1) Add a new DIV immediately under body:

```
<div style="height:200px;width:100%;background:white;">&nbsp;</div>
```

(2) Add this style to your parallax div:

```
<div style="background:white;" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/img/helix-nebula-1400x1400.jpg"></div>
```

That will help with the "window" effect, but I'm not sure why the parallax effect *(slower scroll speed inside window)* not working.

*Of course, you can use external styling, I only used inline styling for purpose of demonstration*